# Conditionally including code based on the existence of a class

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I have two function that do the exact same thing in two different ways. Each uses a different class to accomplish the task:

```
void functionA()
{
  ClassA a = new ClassA();
  a.doWork();
}

void functionB()
{
  ClassB b = new ClassB();
  b.doSomething();
}
```

this is all in a self contained HttpHandler that can be dropped in any project and work - At least thats the goal. FunctionA would be the preferred way of doing things, FunctionB is a fallback. ClassA might not exist in a given project, ClassB will always exist.

Is there a way at runtime to detect is ClassA exists an use functionA and if not use fcuntionB. Also is there a way to compile this if ClassA doesn't exist?  Can I do this with pre-processor stuff (i.e. can I tell at compile time which to include?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, situations like this are much better handled via [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) than trying to determine the existence of a class.

Instead of looking for "ClassA" and "ClassB", it would be a better option to provide 2 interfaces that could be implemented.  You could then use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to attempt to inject an instance of `IInterfaceA`, and if it fails, use an instance of `IInterfaceB` instead.

A good articles to read might be [Martin Fowler's article on IoC](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).  Also, you may want to look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (now included in .NET 4) which makes this very easy in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it with the preprocessor [#if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) directives, then in ClassA add

```
#define ClassA
```

In your `HttpHandler` add

```
#if ClassA
  void function() { ClassA a = new ClassA(); a.doWork(); }
#else
  void function() { ClassB b = new ClassB(); b.doSomething(); }
#endif
```

If possible it would be better to use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and pass it into the constructor of the `HttpHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your class into two files using the `partial` keyword:

```
// MyClass.cs -- include this into every project
public partial class MyClass {
    public void functionB() { ClassB b = new ClassB(); b.doSomething(); }
}

// MyClass.functionA.cs -- include only into projects that have ClassA
public partial class MyClass {
    public void functionA() { ClassA a = new ClassA(); a.doWork(); }
}
```

We do this a few places in our code. I like the "BaseName.Specialty.cs" naming convention, because Solution Explorer will automatically show MyClass.functionA.cs as a sub-node nested under MyClass.cs, the same way it does with .designer.cs files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).  Specifically System.Reflection.Module which can return a list of available types in the module ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.module.gettypes(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.module.gettypes%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)).  I would imagine you can simply cast once you know which type exists.